# How to "reverse" a given CSS3 transition?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

In the documentation for AngularJS's ng-show / ng-hide directive, I discovered a nice visual effect made with CSS3 transforms & transitions:

https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.8/docs/api/ng/directive/ngShow
(see example at the very bottom of the page or go to the following Plunkr)

https://plnkr.co/edit/h2CtJqczey9IfSS6Tovi?p=preview

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" aria-label="Toggle ngShow"><br />
<div class="check-element funky-show-hide" ng-show="checked">
  I show up when your checkbox is checked.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.funky-show-hide.ng-hide-add {
  transform: rotateZ(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.funky-show-hide.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
  transform: rotateZ(-135deg);
}

.funky-show-hide.ng-hide-remove {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.funky-show-hide.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  transform: rotateY(0);
}

.check-element {
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

As a AngularJS developer I understand how it basically works, but as a CSS transitions novice I stumble when I try to modify the given working example.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

**Modify the "hide animation"** (.funky-show-hide.ng-hide-add & .funky-show-hide.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active) **in such a way that the visual effect is the *reverse* of the "show animation"**.

With some try and error, I reached to this:

```
.funky-show-hide.ng-hide-add {
  transform: rotateY(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.funky-show-hide.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/KvYW9vuC2uit2GC14qai?p=preview

But it's not behaving the way I would expect. Especially at the end of the animation (it goes too far to the left).

Comment: A quick fix for the end of the animation is to set the second Y rotation in your css to 112deg.

Comment: 111.4deg seems to be even better :-)
Actually it would be 90deg, but with the `perspective: 1000px` (which I do not yet understand) it needs more Y rotation.